# jQuery AutoComplete Results loaded from partial view

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have searched and unfortunately not found the answer for this. Apologies if this is a duplicate. Can the results from an autocomplete be loaded from a partial?

```
        $('#searchBox2').catcomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 1,
            source: '/api/CheckOrders/Search?searchString=' + inputData,
            select: function (event, ui) {

            }
        }).bind('focus', function () {
            $(this).keydown();
        });
    }
```

I have got the results showing correctly in categories etc but the styling that I want is getting overwritten by the UI styling and its getting a little messy. I was wondering if the results could be loaded from a partial, as this would allow me to style the results more easily. Shown below is how the results are currently shown but UI styling takes over.

```
    function LoadAutoComplete(inputData) {
        $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
            _create: function () {
                this._super();
                this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
            },
            _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {

                var that = this,
                    currentCategory = "";

                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                    var li;
                    if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                        ul.append("<div class='aa-suggestions-category' style='margin-top: 10px;padding-left: 5px;'>" + item.category);
                        currentCategory = item.category;
                    }

                    li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);

                    if (item.category) {
                        li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label);
                    }
                });
            },
            _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
                if (item.category === "Cancelled") {
                    return $("</div><span class='aa-suggestions' style='display: block;'><div class='aa-suggestion'>")
                        .append("<span>" +
                            item.customerID + "</span><span>" +
                            item.customerName + "</span><span>" +
                        item.email + "</span></div></div>")
                        .appendTo(ul);
                }

                else {
                   
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty - The JSFiddle shows a simplified example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/24ur3zfw/1/). The question is, if the autocomplete list can be retrieved from a partial instead of being rendered by the widget. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a proper example, I made use of the Demo: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
    },
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li;
        if (item.category != currentCategory) {
          ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category aa-suggestions-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
          currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        if (item.category) {
          li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label);
        }
      });
    },
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      return $("<li>")
        .attr("data-value", item.value)
        .append("<div class='aa-suggestion'><span>" +
          item.customerID + "</span><span>" +
          item.customerName + "</span><span>" +
          item.email + "</span></div>")
        .addClass("aa-suggestions")
        .appendTo(ul);
    }
  });

  var data = [{
      label: "anders",
      category: "",
      customerID: "01",
      customerName: "anders",
      email: "asmith@example.com"
    },
    {
      label: "andreas",
      category: "",
      customerID: "02",
      customerName: "andreas",
      email: "andreas@example.com"
    },
    {
      label: "antal",
      category: "",
      customerID: "03",
      customerName: "antal",
      email: "antal@example.com"
    },
    {
      label: "annhhx10",
      category: "Products",
      customerID: "04",
      customerName: "ann h",
      email: "annh@example.com"
    },
    {
      label: "annk K12",
      category: "Products",
      customerID: "05",
      customerName: "ann k",
      email: "annk@example.com"
    },
    {
      label: "annttop C13",
      category: "Products",
      customerID: "06",
      customerName: "ann top",
      email: "annt@example.com"
    },
    {
      label: "anders andersson",
      category: "People",
      customerID: "07",
      customerName: "anders anderson",
      email: "aanderson@example.com"
    },
    {
      label: "andreas andersson",
      category: "People",
      customerID: "08",
      customerName: "andreas andersson",
      email: "aandersson@example.com"
    },
    {
      label: "andreas johnson",
      category: "People",
      customerID: "09",
      customerName: "andreas johnson",
      email: "ajohnson@example.com"
    }
  ];

  $("#search").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete-category {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  margin: .8em 0 .2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.aa-suggestion span {
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.aa-suggestion span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="search">Search: </label><input id="search">
```

This continues to use the `ul` and `li` for the menu. If you're using alternate items, please update your post with the proper example. This wraps and assigns the classes you desired for the various elements.

Comment: Thank you for that. That does help a lot. The .addClass is what I was missing. I was struggling with jquery UI adding their styles to the classes overwritting my custom classes. Even now it still does it. I assume there is no actual way to render the autocomplete result list from a partial call as html? If that makes sense. Instead of the widget doing the rendering.

Comment: @MacKey this is a complex widget as it's making use of the Meu widget to show the list of autocomplete options. Adding in your own classes will help you properly define CSS that can take control of the element instead of the UI CSS. You just have to make your CSS Selector more specific: `.ui-autocomplete .aa-suggestions.ui-menu-item div.aa-suggestion.ui-menu-item-wrapper` instead of just `.aa-suggestion`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Yeah that makes sense and will try that. Thank you